# API Version Mismatch Error when Uploading Change Sets into Production

Tags: api, change-set

When I try to upload a change set which includes recently changed or newly created classes(which will in the latest API version), it throws an error message saying that the API versions of some components are not compatible with the production one and I need to downgrade it everytime(currently from 30 to 29). 
I understand the problem and for the moment doing this workaround. But I need to know why the production is in an older version? Is this problem is upto my manager? Not only in change set uploading but in building managed package and some other tasks as well this is happening. 
Please help me to understand this correctly.

NOTE : Found a kind of similar post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16756/apex-class-version-changes-which-leads-to-fail-in-version-compatibility-check) but didn't try to hijacking it since it's somewhat older one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the new SF version (Spring '14) is in its release process. Production environments are always upgraded later than sandboxes. So at this time, the sandboxes are often already on the new version, while Production is still on Winter '14.

In this particular release, there is an extra delay in the production deployment. You can find the full schedules here:
http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2014/01/salesforce-spring-14-release-dates.html

Comment: So the answer to my question is what I'm currently doing is correct? We have to downgrade them manually where it's required until the final release will take place.

Comment: To prevent downgrading, you can do the following: make a new clone of the change set and directly upload it to production (without first uploading to a sandbox). Then it will work without requiring to downgrade.

Comment: That's what I'm doing actually. I got confuse a little with your answer also. My problem is production is v29 and sandbox is v30. But in your answer you are saying "Production environments are always upgraded later than sandboxes". The shared link also saying that Production will be upgraded at last. Have my admin missed something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Sandbox is already upgraded and is on v30. Production is upgraded later and therefore is still on v29. What part is confusing you?

Comment: Yeah, that's my observation too and because of this I have to do whatever I have mentioned. I'm asking whether there is an alternative for this or am I missing something.

Comment: The alternatives are either keep your sandbox instance on the older version (by following the sandbox preview instructions) or save your code in v29. If you are not using new functionality, that will not make any difference. Also see this discussion: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17641/how-do-i-bridge-a-platform-version-difference-between-sandbox-and-production